# how to access to a nested js object in a javascript file on the commandline

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So I am using nodejs and i have js object like below.

```
var settings ={
  "config": {
     "username": "root",
     "password": null,
     "database": "portal_test",
     "host": "122.0.0.4",
     "dialect": "postgres"
  }
}
```

i return that object as a module inside local.env.js. so like this

```
module.exports = settings;
```

now on my command line i am running a sequelize command that takes in a config flag and i pass a path to the config file like below

```
node_modules/.bin/sequelize db:migrate --config server/config/local.env.js
```

Now my question is how can i reference the config object inside of the settings object. I tried something like this below, but it doesnt work.

```
--config server/config/local.env.js[config]
```

Please help. Thanks.
**Note** settings has other objects too, not just config. So i cant do module.exports = settings.config

Comment: Kinda sidestepping here, but seems like you're writing this module, and you're using sequelize - why don't you adapt your module to export `settings.config`?

Comment: well settings has many other objects, too long to paste here. I also use those object in different areas of the projects.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick and dirty way to access your configuration (set up based on your environment:

File where you reference your Sequelize configuration:

```
"use strict";

var fs = require("fs");
var path = require("path");
var Sequelize = require("sequelize");
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development";
var config = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.json')[env];
var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
```

config.json

```
{
  "development": {
    "username": "username",
    "password": null,
    "database": "c9",
    "host": "0.0.0.0",
    "dialect": "mysql"
  },
  "test": {
    "username": "username",
    "password": null,
    "database": "c9",
    "host": "0.0.0.0",
    "dialect": "mysql"
  },
  "production": {
    "username": "username",
    "password": null,
    "database": "c9",
    "host": "0.0.0.0",
    "dialect": "mysql"
  }
}
```

See the following link:
http://techprd.com/angular-js-app-with-postgresql-or-mysql-using-sequelize-js/